# What does "green background" means, when related to "vibration reduction"

Tags: nikon, noise-reduction

I just read in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Nikon_compatible_lenses_with_integrated_autofocus-motor

> Nikon VR/Sigma OS/Tamron VC/Tokina VCM: Optical image stabilization, also called Vibration Reduction, indicated green background, a system used to compensate for vibration and other camera movement.

And I couldn't find any reference to that "green background". What does that mean ?

Comment: @chills42 - Interesting, I never thought of *too localized* in time. I need to think in 4D more :)

Comment: @chills42 Yes, I didn't thought of it being *too localized* because I though it was a new(old) technology that I never heard off...

Comment: Its too localized in the sense that the question only had merit in relation to a specific wikipedia article, one which could easily be corrected (if it indeed was incorrect), thereby also making the question of value only for a very limited time. Too Localized was the correct closure option.

Comment: @woliveirajr it's nothing against you, it was a valid question until it was answered :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is poorly written. *Indicated Green Background* refers to the list below where lenses models with stabilization are highlighted with a green background like the AF-S 16-35mm in the wide-angle section:

[image]

Comment: :) Thanks, now I understood... I edited wikipedia to better phrase it.

Comment: Great! I was about to do that after you accepted the answer so to not confuse people more :)

Comment: Thus rendering this question completely redundant ;)

Comment: Good catch @Itai

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a mistake. Remove "indicated green background" from the statement and it is correct.